# Customising the CMS

Tags: silverstripe

I'm having trouble with how to do something similar to this http://www.silverstripe.org/archive/show/2431.  Basically I want the user to be able to create content and have their ID put into the database with the new content.  I'm sorry if this is fairly obvious.  I am a little stumped though.  I am having trouble wrapping my head around how it will actually work.  I know I can retrieve the current user using the following code but I'm not sure where to go from there.

```
$currentUser = Member::currentUser();
```

Comment: Have you done the first (http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/tutorials/1-building-a-basic-site) and second tutorial (be sure to select the correct version - either 3.0 or 2.4)? Once you've done that, http://www.silverstripe.org/archive/show/2431#post85724 should be pretty self explaining. Or you'll need to rephrase your question, but it's overly broad...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SilverStripe usually the 3rd argument to a FormField is the value, so for example a TextField has the following arguments:

```
new TextField($name = 'myField', $title = 'Please write something in my Field', $value = "yay");
```

but this would not work in the CMS (at least in SilverStripe 2 if you are using a Page, not sure on DataObject) because SilverStripe overwrites all values when it tries to populate the Form with the values of the current object

so you have several alternatives, the 2 easiest alternatives are:

```
class MyContentObject extends DataObject {
    public static $db = array(
        'Text' => 'HTMLText',
    );
    public static $has_one = array(
        'Member' => 'Member',
    )
    public function getCMSFields()  {
        $fields = new FieldSet();
        $fields->push(new Textarea('Text', 'Text'));
        if (!$this->MemberID)
            $this->MemberID = Member::currentUserID();
        $fields->push(new HiddenField('MemberID'));
        return $fields;
    }
}
```

And 2nd option, which is way better in this case, you don't even need a hidden field, you can just set the MemberID right before the record gets written to database by using onBeforeWrite:

```
class MyContentObject extends DataObject {
    public static $db = array(
        'Text' => 'HTMLText',
    );
    public static $has_one = array(
        'Member' => 'Member',
    )
    public function getCMSFields()  {
        $fields = new FieldSet();
        $fields->push(new Textarea('Text', 'Text'));
        return $fields;
    }
    public function onBeforeWrite() {
        // this method will be called every time the object gets saved
        parent::onBeforeWrite();
        if (!$this->MemberID)
            $this->MemberID = Member::currentUserID();
    }
}
```

Comment: nice to see some experienced silverstripe developers taking action here at stackoverflow! +1